# Asp.net mvc project is quite slow for scripts and css

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, bundling-and-minification

I just created a new project with MVC 4 .net 4.5, and I am experiencing some delay when loading the assets. For some fraction of seconds, I see the pages without styles at all, but after a while, the page load correctly. I am using the bundling for my css and scripts, Shouldn't I use it?

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                "~/src/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
                "~/src/css/stylesheet.css",
                "~/src/css/ie-9.css",
                "~/src/css/loader.css",
                "~/src/css/idangerous.swiper.css",
                "~/src/css/base.css"
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issues happen due to browser caching. You browser is loading previously cached css stylesheets. For speed make sure you have implemented gzip http compression in you project.

Comment: This configuration is made on IIS? Or should I make some instalation on the project itself?

Comment: refer this link to get your answer for gzip compression http://stackoverflow.com/a/6992948/2318852